# multiple php version on one server and how to use specific version for specific domain

Tags: php, linux, apache, joomla, debian

Dedicated hosting Debian Linux and php5.2

- website1 is on Joomla 1.0 works with php5.2 (issues with php5.3+)
- website2 need to be on Joomla 3.0 but Joomla 3.0 requires php5.3+

Question:
How can i install php5.3+ and keep php5.2, and how can i adjust apache so that website1 uses php5.2 and website2 uses php5.3+?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use different ports on fast cgi for the various PHP versions.

Another approach: http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server